# MySQL: Is there a way to get data for all dates between two dates even when there are no date rows?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have an SELECT query like the following:

```
SELECT orders.date
     , SUM(orders.amount) AS total_amount 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE orders.date >= '2021-04-01' 
   AND orders.date <= '2021-04-05';
 GROUP BY orders.date
```

In the table, let's say I don't have any records for the dates 2021-04-03 and 2021-04-04, obviously there won't be any sum data returned for those two dates.

My question, is it possible to have a query that would return the blank dates as 0 total_amount so I can get the results like this?

| date | total_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | 11111 |
| 2021-04-02 | 22222 |
| 2021-04-03 | 0 |
| 2021-04-04 | 0 |
| 2021-04-05 | 12345 |

Thank you!

Comment: Generate base dates list (in recursive CTE, for example) then join your data table to it.

Comment: Or just handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I didn't know about CTE. Interesting concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate a "calendar" table containing all dates which you want to appear in your final report.  Then, left join it to your current table and take the sums.  In lieu of an actual calendar table, we can use an inline subquery:

```sql
SELECT
    d.date,
    COALESCE(SUM(o.amount), 0) AS total_amount
FROM
(
    SELECT '2021-04-01' AS date UNION ALL        -- replace this ad-hoc table
    SELECT '2021-04-02' UNION ALL                -- with a bona-fide table
    SELECT '2021-04-03' UNION ALL                -- containing all dates
    SELECT '2021-04-04' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-05'
) d
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON o.date = d.date
GROUP BY
    d.date
ORDER BY
    d.date;
```

Comment: It's all Latin to me

Comment: In this age of CTE, I just can't bring myself to do it. Sic transit gloria mundi